# Why is build not being read in my package.json?

Tags: reactjs, electron, package.json, electron-builder

I'm trying to build an electron app with react, but my windows options are not being read.

I first run react-scripts build to create the build folder. I then run npm run dist to run the build configuration. However, it builds the wrong target (the default nsis instead of msi).

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "public/electron.js",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/styled-components": "^4.1.16",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-icons": "^3.7.0",
    "react-picker": "^1.2.14",
    "react-scripts": "^3.0.1",
    "react-spinners": "^0.5.4",
    "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.3.1",
    "tslint": "^5.17.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": {
      "appId": "myApp",
      "extends": null,
      "win": {
        "title": "My App",
        "version": "1.0",
        "target": "msi",
        "icon": "src/CITIcon.ico"
      }
    },
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-start": "electron .",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^5.0.3",
    "electron-builder": "^20.43.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
    "tslint-react": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

When I run npm run dist, I get the following output

```
> windowsandon@0.1.0 dist 
> build

  • electron-builder version=20.43.0
  • loaded parent configuration preset=react-cra
  • description is missed in the package.json appPackageFile={myPath}\package.json
  • author is missed in the package.json appPackageFile={myPath}\package.json
  • writing effective config file=dist\builder-effective-config.yaml
  • no native production dependencies
  • packaging       platform=win32 arch=x64 electron=5.0.3 appOutDir=dist\win-unpacked
  • default Electron icon is used reason=application icon is not set
  • building        target=nsis file=dist\myApp Setup 0.1.0.exe archs=x64 oneClick=true perMachine=false
  • building block map blockMapFile=dist\myApp Setup 0.1.0.exe.blockmap
```

The target should be msi and the extends null should have negated the "loaded parent configuration" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work. I had to take the build portion out of my scripts object, and specify an icon path.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "electron-start": "electron .",
    "pack": "build --dir",
    "dist": "build"
  },
  "build": {
    "appId": "MyApp",
    "extends": null,
    "win": {
      "icon": "./img/icon.ico",
      "target": "msi"
    }
  },
```